# When was the script started?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

What I want is,

```
-bash-3.2$ ps -aef | grep 29137
jeeadm    9794  1190  0 09:22 pts/2    00:00:00 grep 29137
jeeadm   29137     1  0 Sep02 ?        00:00:21 Java
```

Second Row, Fifth Column entry, as in the output it's just showing the date, Anyway to get the full time-stamp?

Comment: Does `/proc/29137` exist on your system? `stat` a file in there to get the exact time.

Comment: @glennjackman actually that doesn't work. The `/proc/<PID>` time will be the timestamp the (virtual) directory was created. It gets created the first time something tries to access it (`ls`, `ps`, etc).

Comment: @Keys this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731234/how-to-get-the-start-time-of-a-long-running-linux-process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `lstart` field for this:

```
# ps -aefO lstart | head       
  PID                  STARTED S TTY          TIME COMMAND
31379 Sat Aug  2 21:31:11 2014 S pts/3    00:00:00 zsh
31399 Sat Aug  2 21:31:11 2014 S pts/3    00:00:00  \_ vim
27313 Sat Aug 30 13:19:27 2014 S pts/4    00:00:20 zsh
27193 Sat Aug 30 13:18:11 2014 S pts/2    00:00:19 zsh
25196 Wed Sep  3 22:37:57 2014 S pts/16   00:00:00 zsh
25231 Wed Sep  3 22:38:00 2014 S pts/16   00:00:00  \_ sudo
25241 Wed Sep  3 22:38:04 2014 S pts/16   00:00:02      \_ zsh
24642 Sat Aug 30 12:50:48 2014 S pts/0    00:00:20 zsh
23366 Thu Sep  4 08:47:30 2014 S pts/18   00:00:00 zsh
```

Comment: what's the appended `0` for, after `-aef`?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ps -p 11517 -o stime
```

after a day (midnight) ps whill show startday, rather than hour,

after a month, you'll get mon and year,

after a year, you'll get starting year.

Answer (score 1):

To find out the timestamp when the process started, you have to calc a bit. Use this command:

```
echo "$(date +%s) - $(ps -o etime --no-headers -p $pid | \
awk -F'[:-]' '{print ($4+($3*60)+($2*60*60)+($1*24*60*60))}')" | bc -l
```

The value of `$pid` should be the process id.

**Explanation:**

- `echo "$(date +%s)`: print the timestamp of now
- `ps -o etime --no-headers -p $pid`: print the elapsed time of the process without headers
- `awk -F'[:-]'`: set the delimiter of `awk` to `:` and `-` because the time will be printed in the following format: `dd-hh:mm:ss`
- `'{print ($4+($3*60)+($2*60*60)+($1*24*60*60))}'` calculate the values in seconds
- `bc -l`: and pipe the output to `bc` (`timestamp_now - elapsed_seconds = timespamp_at_process_start`)

For exmaple i tested it with the init process of a system that runs for 42 days. The output was `1406124152`, which is the `07 / 23 / 14 @ 2:02:31pm UTC`.

Comment: Quite a calculation! Kudos for your efforts :) but then thought of using the `lstart` option as need it li'l often..